# Determine the count of users who access the document in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Determine the count of users who access the document, and show the count on a column - In the document management system, when the attachment is opened for viewing/reading, we need to capture the count of users who viewed the document. This information must be displayed in a different column or the best preferred way of displaying the count of number of viewers/readers.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking and reporting on Document views is possible using the Audit Logging feature in SP:

- Configuring Audit Logging: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102866204.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739
- View Audit Log Reports: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102772739.aspx

If you want to then take that Audit Log data and push the counts into a Document Library as metadata, you'll likely need to write a solution that either reads that data directly from the Audit Log or by publishing it from the Audit Log Excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable auditing on the library. using timer job uspade the count of the files opened. But this count will be updated if document is accessed via sharepoint site through browser. In case if same document is accessed using web service to display on (for e.g.) iPad applciation then count will not be updated.